# Lógica ! quero incluir niveis no meu jogo usando while ou for

Tags: python, lógica

```python
print('*********************************')
print('*     jogo de advinhacao 2       *')
print('*********************************')
num_secreto = 36
total_tentativas = 3

for rodada in range(1, total_tentativas + 1):
    print('Tentativa {} de {} '.format(rodada, total_tentativas))

    chute = int(input('Digite o seu numero: '))
    print('Você digitou:', chute)
    

    acertou = chute == num_secreto
    maior = chute > num_secreto
    menor = chute < num_secreto

    if(acertou):
        print('Você acertou!')
        break
    elif(chute > num_secreto):
        print('Você errou! O seu numero é maior que o numero secreto.')
    elif(chute < num_secreto):
        print('Você errou! o seu numero é menor que o numero secreto.')
```

Agora como faço para o usuario escolha o nível que ele quer jogar(nivel1 = tentaivas = 20, nivel2 = tentativas 10, nivel 3 = tentaivas 5).

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários. Veja também [ask] e faça o nosso [tour].

Comment: Veja se a função embutida [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#input) o ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você pode utilizar a função input() para solicitar ao usuário que informe qual será o nível desejado.

Em seguida, pode utilizar o loop while de modo que caso nível informado pelo usuário não esteja informado na lista ["1", "2", "3"], o programa solicitará novamente ao usuário que informe o nível correto.

Em seguida, esse número é convertido em inteiro e basta utilizar o if e elif para informar o número de tentativas para cada nível, da seguinte forma:

```
print('*********************************')
print('*     jogo de advinhacao 2      *')
print('*********************************')

print('\nEscolha o nivel de dificuldade:\n\nNivel 1 (Facil) - 20 tentativas \nNivel 2 (Medio) - 10 tentativas \nNivel 3 (Difícil) - 5 tentativas')

num_secreto = 36

nivel = input('\nDigite o nível desejado (1, 2 ou 3): ')

while nivel not in ["1", "2", "3"]:
    nivel = input('\nOpção inválida! \nDigite o nível desejado (1, 2 ou 3): ')

nivel = int(nivel)

if nivel == 1:
    total_tentativas = 20
elif nivel == 2:
    total_tentativas = 10
elif nivel == 3:
    total_tentativas = 5

print(f"Nivel escolhido {nivel}. \n")

for rodada in range(1, total_tentativas + 1):
    print('Tentativa {} de {} '.format(rodada, total_tentativas))

    chute = int(input('Digite o seu numero: '))
    print('Você digitou:', chute)
    

    acertou = chute == num_secreto
    maior = chute > num_secreto
    menor = chute < num_secreto

    if(acertou):
        print('Você acertou!')
        break
    elif(maior):
        print('Você errou! O seu numero é maior que o numero secreto.')
    elif(menor):
        print('Você errou! o seu numero é menor que o numero secreto.')
```

Comment: Por que não utilizar `maior` e `menor` nas duas últimas condições?

Comment: é uma opção também, mas caso ele tenha diversos niveis (1 a 10), imagino que seja correto utilizar if.

Comment: `elif(chute > num_secreto)` poderia ser `elif(maior)`

Comment: tem razão Woss, é que nesse caso eu não cheguei a alterar o código depois do laço for